# PHP preg_replace HREF

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In short, I'm utilizing `pre_replace` to find style sheets and essentially proxy this experience for viewers on my website, I use the external domain and `prepend` it to the current `href`. The style sheet starts like so.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/base.css">
```

I will take the `href` and `prepend` the domain to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.website.com/assets/css/base.css">
```

My issue is, when I encounter a site that does not include HTTP/HTTPS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.website.com/assets/css/base.css">
```

Then my current preg replace would not function and return the stylesheet to the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.website.com//cdn.website.com/assets/css/base.css">
```

Is it possible to create some sort of `If then` with `preg_replace` to not manipulate the "//" hrefs and only replace the ones with no absolute base domain?

**Current `preg_replace` being used:**

```
$html = file_get_contents($website_url);
$domain = 'website.com';
$html = preg_replace("/(href|src)\=\"([^(http)])(\/)?/", "$1=\"$domain$2", $html);
echo $html;
```

Comment: simple: don't use regexes. Use a DOM parser and then it's a simple string replace operation once you've got the `href` attribute's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `if/then/else` conditionals in regex, although not really necessary for this to work:

```
(?!(href|src)=)(\")\/(\\w+.+)(\">)
```

Code:

```
$html = file_get_contents($website_url);
$domain = 'http://website.com';
$result = preg_replace("/(?!(href|src)=)(\")\/(\\w+.+)(\">)/u", "$2$domain/$3$4", $html);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://website.com/assets/css/base.css">
```

Example:

**http://regex101.com/r/kU7pF1**

Answer (score 1):

`[^(href)]` is not a negation. It's still a character class.

You are looking for a [`(?!...)` negative lookahead](http://www.google.com/search?q=negative%20lookahead):

```
 ~  (href|src) =\" (?!href:)  \/?  ~x
```

While I dispute the SO meme and overgeneralization of firing up a DOM traversal for each trivia, it should be noted that regex is often only appropriate for normalized and well-known HTML input; not if your task is proxying arbitrary websites.

Answer (score 0):

```
function alterLinks($html) {

  $ret = '';

  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML($html);
  $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach ($links as $alink) {
    $href = $alink->getAttribute('href'); 
    $aMungedLink = $this->mungeHref($href);
    $alink->setAttribute("href",$aMungedLink);
  }

  $ret = $dom->saveHTML();
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Consider editing your answer to add that context.

Comment: Some of the comments in this thread involved regular expressions.  I recently had a "change hrefs" problem writing a plugin to a dynamic CMS, so I could optionally output staticHTML instead.  I tried but failed to get preg_replace and regular expressions to work.  The code above is clean and simple. It worked for me.  I didn't write the mungeHref($href) function above because my needs were different than yours.  That's the easy part anyway.

Comment: fwiw I used almost identical codes to rework the "src" attributes for all images in a dynamic HTML page, so it could then be written out as static HTML.  But that's a different topic.